# MySQL error unknown collation

Tags: mysql, laravel

After attempting to run a migration in Laravel 4 I received the following error:

```
[PDOException]                                              
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation: ''
```

Here is my database connection configuration;

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
),
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the reason behind but after Google i found this [thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,195219,197613#msg-197613) discussing the same issue and resolved after clearing cookies. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grab the latest source code by running composer update from the root folder of your installation. Else update your array as below.

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'   => '',
 ),
```