# Django testing MySQL permission

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am going through the Django tutorial and I've run into some trouble because I'm using MySQL as my database.

When I run

```
    python manage.py test polls
```

I get

```
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
    Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'USER123'@'%' to database 'test_USER123'")
    Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_USER123', or 'no' to cancel:
```

This is my settings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'USER123',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
            'USER': 'USER123',
            'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
            'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
}
```

}

I was wondering if anyone would explain to me what's wrong and what's going on. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error unknown collation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582105/mysql-error-unknown-collation)

Comment: @Hedde how is a PHP issue raising the same error message going to be helpful in this case?

Comment: sorry i entered the wrong error message. it is updated now!

Comment: @robertklep this issue has nothing todo with either php or python/django it's mysql related, a collation is clearly missing

Comment: @Liondancer you have to create a user `USER123` with password `PASSWORD` in MySQL first. [Look here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql) (be sure to use your own username/password/databasename, though)

Comment: Sorry I was playing around with some settings that were fixes but none of them worked. I was told to try adding TEST_COLLATION to my database dictionary but it did not help. I added the wrong error message at first but it is updated now

Comment: @Hedde if it has nothing to do with PHP or Python/Django, I fail to see how it would be a duplicate of a question obviously related to some PHP framework.

Comment: @robertklep I'm getting this error. 

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

I'm not sure how to give create privileges to the user i logged on to mysql with

Comment: I logged onto mysql with mysql -r USER123 -p PASSWORD

Comment: @Liondancer you have to perform those `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` queries as the database administrator user.

Comment: @robertklep you should have answered this question, I would have given you a check! and upvote!